# Re using spark hdfs checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

We use Spark 2.4.3 for stream processing. This is on AWS EMR. There is a possibility of cluster failure in EMR and hence we decided to back up the data to S3 at regular intervals.

Reference : https://cm.engineering/using-hdfs-to-store-spark-streaming-application-checkpoints-2146c1960d30

Now, when we try to restore checkpoints generated in one cluster in another cluster, we get this error :

```
User class threw exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from ip-xx-xx-xx-215/xx.xx.xx.215 to ip-xx-xx-xx-42.YYYYYYYY-Y.YYYYY.internal:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

In this ip-xx-xx-xx-42.YYYYYYYY-Y.YYYYY.internal:8020 is the older cluster. We opened the checkpoint files in a text editor. We could find the IP address present there.

Is there a way for us to avoid this?

Comment: I don’t know how saving checkpoints work. But I'll say if you are copying data from HDFS to S3 on a regular interval, why aren’t you using EMRFS (s3) instead of HDFS? You don’t have to backup anything, you will read write directly to s3.

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti, we compared checkpointing latencies and found HDFS to have the lowest value. Also, cost !

Comment: Yeah thats make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Spark streams stores 2 types of checkpointing data

1. Metadata checkpointing - Saving of the information defining the streaming computation to fault-tolerant storage like HDFS. This is
   used to recover from failure of the node running the driver of the
   streaming application.
2. Data checkpointing - Saving of the generated RDDs to reliable storage. This necessary in some stateful transformations that
   combine data across multiple batches.

More details can be found from the link [1].

This is the reason why the New cluster namenode is trying connect to the old cluster namenode but the as the old cluster was already terminated you got no route to host exception. As the checkpointed data also uses metadata information which has the cluster details ,  checkpointed data can be only used on the same cluster and cannot be transferred to different clusters for processing.

[1]https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing